# "C днем рождения" или "Co днем рождения"?

Tags: орфография, предлоги

Could you please tell me whether people say "C днем рождения" or "Co  днем рождения" ? And why.
Thank you very very much.
Best wishes,
Peter

Comment: На тему С или СО см. таже: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36419/%d0%a1-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc  
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416857/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be  
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13135/%d0%a1%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Предлог "с" или "со"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416857/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be)

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: **C днем рождения!** (Обычно с восклицательным знаком.)
Почему? Эта тема уже не раз обсуждалась (см. мой комментарий к вопросу).